# 'Invisible' boot loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot

## SYMPTOM

Windows \ Ubuntu 16.10 dual boot install does not show grub menu (black screen). When the 'invisible' boot loader is waiting for input, pushing the arrow key down 4 times will boot Windows partition, doing nothing boots 16.10.   I suspect that grub was installed.

Update: monitor reports 'frequency out of range' during boot loader wait for user input

## GOAL

Boot loader presents menu options to boot from Windows or Ubuntu

## QUESTIONS

What diagnostics can be performed to better understand the current state and advance to the goal?

Comment: Hold down the left shift key at boot time and see if that causes the GRUB menu to appear. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema  No GRUB Menu with left shift key

Comment: If UEFI, you use escape key, not shift key. You may have to press several times, but do not hold it like shift key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. boot to Ubuntu
2. open a terminal from the Unity dashboard
3. type `cd /etc/default`
4. edit the file `grub` with either `sudo pico grub` or `gksu gedit grub`
5. change the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

6. save the edited file, and quit whichever editor you chose
7. type `sudo update-grub`
8. reboot the computer
9. check to make sure that you have the latest/correct video driver installed

Comment: The monitor indicated  "frequency out of  range" unless Windows was active.  I swapped out the monitor and Grub menus were present.  Maybe this is a video output problem.

Comment: That's what the nomodeset parameter attempts to solve. It's probably a video driver problem though. Did you make the changes in the grub file?

Comment: Yes: instruction 7: sudo update-grub was executed.  Your assistance is appreciated

Comment: So are you working OK now? With the original monitor, or the swapped in monitor? If the latter, try the former. Did the nomodeset help?

Comment: It only works with second monitor: only one resolution available.    I think that the problem now is to find and install a driver for a [AMD/ATI] RS480 [Radeon Xpress 200 Series] and 16.10?

Comment: You can also edit `/etc/default/grub` and uncomment the line that has `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` and then `sudo update-grub`. That should work with any monitor/video system. But yes, finding the proper video driver is paramount.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48444/discussion-between-gatorback-and-heynnema).